# TypeError: data.map is not a function Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs,I am using nextjs,I am trying to get/fetch data via Api
But i am getting following error

```
TypeError: data.map is not a function
```

Here is my code (component/Slider.js)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
const Slider = () => {
 const [data,setData]=useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
        const getData =async() =>{
            const response =await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/sliderinfos");
            const data = await response.json();
              setData(data);
        };
        getData();
  });
  
  return (
    <div className="main-banner header-text">
  
  {data.map((article) => (
      <li key={article.id}>{article.id}</li>
    ))}
    </div>
     )
    }
    
    export default Slider

Here is my json response
{"data":[{"id":1,"attributes":{"category":"FASHION","createdAt":"2022-07-19T04:52:38.578Z","updatedAt":"2022-07-19T04:52:40.001Z","publishedAt":"2022-07-19T04:52:39.996Z","title":"Morbi Dapibus Condimentum","createdby":"Admin","description":"Lorem Ipsum one"}},{"id":2,"attributes":{"category":"NATURE","createdAt":"2022-07-19T05:07:59.368Z","updatedAt":"2022-07-19T05:08:00.606Z","publishedAt":"2022-07-19T05:08:00.603Z","title":"Donec Porttitor Augue At Velit","createdby":"Admin","description":"Lorem Ipsum two"}},{"id":3,"attributes":{"category":"LIFESTYLE","createdAt":"2022-07-19T05:11:10.975Z","updatedAt":"2022-07-19T05:11:12.065Z","publishedAt":"2022-07-19T05:11:12.062Z","title":"Best HTML Templates On TemplateMo","createdby":"Admin","description":"Lorem Ipsum three."}},{"id":4,"attributes":{"category":"FASHION","createdAt":"2022-07-19T05:12:26.883Z","updatedAt":"2022-07-19T05:12:28.013Z","publishedAt":"2022-07-19T05:12:28.010Z","title":"Responsive And Mobile Ready Layouts","createdby":"Admin","description":"Lorem Ipsum four."}},{"id":5,"attributes":{"category":"NATURE","createdAt":"2022-07-19T05:14:02.093Z","updatedAt":"2022-07-19T05:14:03.204Z","publishedAt":"2022-07-19T05:14:03.200Z","title":"Cras Congue Sed Augue Id Ullamcorper","createdby":"admin","description":"Lorem Ipsum five."}},{"id":6,"attributes":{"category":"LIFESTYLE","createdAt":"2022-07-19T05:15:53.198Z","updatedAt":"2022-07-19T05:15:54.213Z","publishedAt":"2022-07-19T05:15:54.210Z","title":"Suspendisse Nec Aliquet Ligula","createdby":"admin","description":"Lorem Ipsum six"}}],"meta":{"pagination":{"page":1,"pageSize":25,"pageCount":1,"total":6}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you trying to map over data that is an object

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getData =async() =>{
            const response =await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/sliderinfos");
            const data = await response.json();
              setData(data.data);
        };
        getData();
  });
```

Replace data by data.data to get your array in your state

Answer (score 0):

Initially `data` is an array:

```
const [data,setData]=useState([]);
```

But when you update it to your JSON response, it's an object:

```
setData(data);
```

Because your JSON response is an object:

```
{"data":[/*...*/]}
```

That object *has a property* which is an array.  Did you mean to set the state to that property?:

```
setData(data.data);
```

Comment: in my api i am getting data (6 records) but with above code i am getting data with 2 records

Comment: @John: What indication do you have of these "6 records"?  The JSON response shown isn't even structurally valid and can't be parsed, but it shows/implies only two records in that array.

Comment: i am getting 6 record in api but showing 2 records in loop (data.map) , kindly tell me how can i fix this

Comment: @John: Simply *repeating* that you think you're getting 6 records doesn't make it true.  Again, what actual indication do you have of this?  Can you show your entire API response here?  Because the response you're showing in the question, once its syntax errors are corrected, contains **only 2 records**.

Comment: i mentioned 2 records but actually there is 6 records

Comment: let me update my response

Comment: updated my json response

Comment: @John: The exact code and data, copied and pasted as-is (only replacing the AJAX operation with the hard-coded result), [works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-breeze-ftsm84?file=/src/Slider.js).  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: i tried with your code (codesandbox) but that also showing me 2 record/number (5,6)

Comment: @John: Then something else must be wrong with what you're doing, because [it clearly works](https://imgur.com/a/I0jNxXc).  If, as you state, when you go to the sandbox link I provided and you are only seeing the numbers 5 and 6 in the list, then something is *very broken* about your web browser.  The above sandbox link is showing the numbers 1-6 in every browser I have.